# WPF RichTextBox setting the Paragraph.Margin property

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

This one is really driving me nuts. The RichTextBox by default inserts an extra line before the start of a new paragraph. I gather setting the Paragraph Margin property to zero will prevent this behavior but can only see examples in xaml... I've tried

```
.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.MarginProperty, 0.0)
```

But that throws an error telling me '0' is not a valid value for property 'Margin'

and

```
.Resources.Add(Paragraph.MarginProperty, 0.0)
```

but that has no effect...

Answer (score 3):

Margin is a [`Thickness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type --

```
.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0))
```

To add to `Resources`, add a style targeting the `Paragraph` type:

```
Style paragraphStyle = new System.Windows.Style { TargetType = typeof(Paragraph) };
paragraphStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { 
    Property = Paragraph.MarginProperty, 
    Value = new Thickness(0) });
.Resources.Add(null, paragraphStyle);
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that as well - but clearly I didn't as it works perfectly.